# Twitter Integration in Cocos2d-iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game in which i have to post scores on my Facebook and twitter a/c.

I have written this code but it not working. It's neither giving any error nor any popup for posting something .

```
  - (void) SLComposeViewControllerButtonPressed: (id) sender{

 if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{

    AppDelegate * myDelegate = (((AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Just scored %d. ", 10];

    SLComposeViewController*fvc = [SLComposeViewController
                                   composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [fvc setInitialText:string];
     [[myDelegate navController]  presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please give me valid solution of this problem.

Comment: Does it enter the condition block if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) ? It's most probably the case

Comment: And what may be the second cause is that i assume that navController property is on UINavigationController. So you could try  [[[[myDelegate navController] viewcontrollers] objectAtIndex:0] presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Its completely work with cocoa touch but not with cocos2d because of CCScene .and your given is also not working. i need solution for cocos2d

Comment: I have made a solution with adding a view controller                   [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:viewController.view];
        [viewController presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CCDirector` is a subclass of `UIViewController` in iOS. So it can be used for presenting modal viewControllers.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Update: [Here is a DOC](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/_c_c_director_8h_source.html)

```
  #ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
  #define CC_VIEWCONTROLLER UIViewController
  #elif defined(__CC_PLATFORM_MAC)
  #define CC_VIEWCONTROLLER NSObject
  #endif

  @interface CCDirector : CC_VIEWCONTROLLER
```